# How to add a Transport dynamically to an Axis2 Service?

Tags: apache-axis

I have an Axis2 service exposed in HTTPS. I want to add HTTP transport dynamically to the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add a transport dynamically as bellow,

```
axisService.addExposedTransport("http");
```